Can I raise floor height and insulation value with a layer of 1/2" EPS foam?
All of my floors are coming up (water damage as a result of fire) in my main living space. While they're up, I've been wanting to switch the kitchen from hardwood to tile - and while I'm doing that, I'd take the opportunity to heat the floor.
Doing so would require either a transition up into the kitchen, or boosting the entire floor. Can I lay down 1/2" EPS foam over the entire house (which would give me a free insulation boost in the sunroom which doesn't currently have a well insulated floor) and then hardwood/laminate/vinyl overtop? I can then run the heated floor in the kitchen with 5/16" pex and gain the 1/2" that I need.
I see no issues with this, but having never installed real hardwood (if I choose to go that route) I'm not sure if they're generally floating (would make sense given the expansion) or nailed down, which they couldn't be if I used foam.

No. Virtually no flooring is permitted by the manufacturer to be installed over foam without a rigid subfloor between. You'll void all warranties and invite failure of the flooring.
You would need a proper subfloor over the foam, which involves something stiff enough to not sag into the foam under the force of fasteners or working loads. Ideally seams would be either linked (tongue and groove) or supported with wood framing. A person could lay the foam, then trace and cut channels for sleeper joists of the same thickness where butt joints occur.

Interesting - so if I did foam and then another layer of 1/4" ply subfloor, would that be considered a "rigid subfloor"?

No. 1/4" material is not "subfloor". If anything, it's an underlayment.

5/8" is considered the minimum for subfloor, with 3/4" being recommended.
